# the mystery of the vanishing web form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, raphael

http://poland.inbulgaria.org/search

This web form, based on jQuery, but also including a SVG map control made with Raphael, appears correctly in Opera 11.51, as well as IE 8, but, for some reason, doesn't render at all in Firefox 6. Any clue why?

Comment: It displays for me in firefox 6

Comment: Doesn't display on mine, Firefox 6 too. I should mention that I'm on a Mac.

Comment: there is a form at the left but no svg map for me, ff 3.6 + windows

Comment: I don't see the center form on neither Chrome nor FF6 on Linux. I can see it under Opera 11.

Comment: I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined, mybga_advsearch.js:326` under Chrome.

Comment: @BenjaminSeiller, julkiewicz - at some point I removed the <canvas> tag to see whether this is the culprit. This is probably the reason for what you both saw.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Frustrated, I asked this question in a "share your mood" thread on some tiny forum with literally 5 users, and... I got a solution.

Adblock is blocking the form.

Yeah, silly as that. (:

Maybe it's because it's called Advanced Search, and there are a lot of DIVs with classes starting with *adv*.

Now that's something I've never heard happen to anyone else...

Answer (score 2):

First thing I noticed is that you aren't escaping some of your class names and ID's with quotation marks, eg

```
<div class=advBox id=advOfferType>
```

Firebug is giving NaN values for the positioning of these elements which is a bad sign. Escape those IDs & class names, then get back to us.

Comment: I'm currently iteratively running the W3C XHTML validator and fixing my page, and I've gotten the errors from 200+ to 80-ish, mainly thanks to your tip. The form still doesn't show in FF though.

Comment: I'm quite confident that it'll work when you get that html validated. For example, the html tag is shortclosed, that itself could be causing the issue. I'll eat my words if it validates and still has the issue!